# High performance dom add and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Sidenote: I'm using JQuery, but not any third party table components (nor could I for now).

My problem is that I should be able to show a lot (10000) of messages that are passing by - each second there will be hundreds of new messages, and they should be added to the bottom. When we reach the 10000 limit, the old messages will be removed from the beginning.

There should also be a possibility to filter these messages, so when the user types something to the search box, only rows containing the words will be shown.

The site structure is this simple:

```
<div id="message_container">
 <p>Message 1</p>
 <p>Message 2</p>
 <p>Message 3</p>
 <p>Message 4</p>
</div>
```

Currently I add multiple messages at once, which is quite fast:

```
var newMessagesHtml = [];
// messages = new messages
for(var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii ++) {
   newMessagesHtml.push("<p>Message</p>");
}
$("#message_container").append(newMessagesHtml.join(''));
```

I think that is not a problem (I cache the query of message_container). However, when we hit the 10000 limit and start removing the old messages from the top, that is slow. How should it be done? I've tried to use jquery to filter n first messages and remove them, but the browser starts to become unresponsive. Is it better to remove multiple messages at once, or one at the time?

How would you do these without 3rd party components, except the JQuery?
1) Add and remove many elements each second
2) Filter out the elements we don't want to see

Thanks for all the help and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a practical semi implementation you could try this. I added the tips from @Jos de Jong above, to allow for smooth adding / removing / searching

The QueryList class adds the possibility to add/remove messages, your queryList.items contains the list of actual items, and by setting the maxItems you can easily configure how many items you want to see :)

On add, dom elements are added, on remove dom elements also get removed again, search just toggles a css class (with removal of parent dom node)

The example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/j4nLh9k1/

Code for the queryList

```
;(function($) {
    function QueryItem(parentElement, value) {
        this.parentElement = parentElement;
        this.value = value;
        this.element = undefined;
    }

    function QueryList(element, options) {
        var that = this;
        this.items = [];
        this.currentQuery = undefined;

        this.suspendLayout = function() {
            element._oldNode = element.parentNode;
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        };

        this.resumeLayout = function() {
            element._oldNode.appendChild(element);
        };

        this.add = function(item) {
            var p, qry = new QueryItem(element, item);
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            if (this.currentQuery && item.indexOf(this.currentQuery) === -1) {
                p.className = 'hidden';
            }
            p.innerHTML = qry.value;
            qry.element = p;
            qry.parentElement = element;
            qry.parentElement.appendChild(p);
            this.items.push(qry);
            if (this.items.length > options.maxItems) {
                this.remove(0, this.items.length - options.maxItems);
            }
        }

        this.remove = function(index, length) {
            var i, item, len;
            for (i = 0, len = length || 1; i < len; i++) {
                item = this.items[index];
                item.parentElement.removeChild(item.element);
                item.element = undefined;
            }
            this.items.splice(index, length);
        };

        this.search = function(txt) {
            var i, len, item;
            this.currentQuery = txt;
            this.suspendLayout();
            for (i = 0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++) {
                item = this.items[i];
                if (txt && item.value.indexOf(txt) === -1) {
                    item.element.className = 'hidden';
                } else {
                    item.element.className = '';
                }
            }
            this.resumeLayout();
        };
    }

    $.fn.queryList = function(options) {
        if (typeof this.selector === 'undefined' || this.length !== 1) {
            throw 'QueryList has to be linked to exactly one item';
        }
        var qry = new QueryList(this[0], options);
        this.data('queryList', qry);
        return qry;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and as a test main method

```
$(function() {
    var queryList = $('#msgContainer').queryList({
        maxItems: 10000
    }), index = 0, i, interval;
    queryList.add('hi there');
    for (i = 0; i < 7000; i++) {
        queryList.add('item ' + i);
    }
    console.log(queryList.items);

    $('#buttonSearch').on('click', function(e) {
        var svalue = $('#inputSearch').val();
        queryList.search(svalue);
    });

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        queryList.suspendLayout();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            queryList.add('Additional message ' + ((index * 100) + i));
        }
        queryList.resumeLayout();
        index++;
    }, 1000);

    $('#buttonStopInterval').on('click', function(e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Do not use jQuery nor HTML strings. Instead create your messages as DOM elements and append/remove them using JavaScript calls, like:

```
var newMessagesHtml = [];
var container = document.getElementById('message_container');
for(var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii ++) {
   var msg = document.createElement('p');
   msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messages[i]));
   container.appendChild(msg);
}
```

If you add a lot of messages at once, you could remove the `message_container` element from the DOM, add all messages to it, and attach it to the DOM again, something like:

```
var container = document.getElementById('message_container');
var parent = container.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(container);

// ...append a lot of messages...

parent.appendChild(container);
```

Option 2:

You could try [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/). It manages a virtual DOM and minimizes the updates on the real DOM (which is the bottleneck).

Comment: Oh I just tried and removing the container from the dom to append nodes it, doesn't make the existing messages to disappear from the browser? Didn't realize that.

Comment: No, if you append the container again in one at the end. It can be faster when doing a lot of DOM operations, but can be slower as well.  You will have to test if it improves performance in your use case.